# Caddy with Cloudflare 502 bad gateway error

Tags: cloudflare, caddy, caddyfile

I have app running on port - `3000` and running with caddy reverse proxy at port 80 and 443.

It works fine, but as soon as I switch to cloudflare, the site gets down and shows error `502 bad gateway`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got this solved by installing `tls.dns.cloudflare` plugin.